# What's the most efficient way to generate metadata for lots of non-generative NFTs?

Tags: nft, opensea, meta-data

I know that there are tutorials to generate metadata as part of generative art (i.e. layered art for example using the Hashlips Engine), but what about for art that isn't generated by layering traits on top of each other? Like for example, a photo collection?
Right now, all I can think of is having images with different attributes grouped into folders and subfolders, then write a script in JS to assign the metadata to each image based on the folder and subfolder names.
Just wondering if anyone has a better idea.

Comment: You mentioned AI generated art but the question says non-generative. Are you generating the art?

Comment: I edited the question and removed the AI generated art part to make it less "contradicting". I referred to the definition of "non-generative" NFTs as those that weren't generated using different layers of traits in Javascript. i.e. I already have a set of images (say that I have hundreds of them) and I want to find the most efficient way to assign metadata corresponding to each image (without having to go through each metadata file and individually assign traits corresponding to each image.

Comment: Do the photos have clearly defined attributes? e.g. background is green, yellow, or blue; filter: dark, light, pastel; rotation: -45, 0, 45 degrees etc. Or are they very diverse? e.g. some photos are portraits, others are nature landscapes, others abstract art?

Comment: by metadata do you mean the attributes? if so, this is not metadata etched into the NFTs are they? attributes, unlike metadata, seem to be added at the website layer, not on the blockchain.